# how to get the size of the map using the pointer of the map?

Tags: c++, pointers, dictionary

I have a question regrading how to use the pointer to a map to get the size of the map:

```
map<int, string> mapList;

map<int, string>* getMapList()
{
   return &mapList;
}

void main()
{
   map<int, string>* mapPointer = getMapList();
}
```

then how to use this `pointer` to get the size of `map`?

Comment: `mapPointer->size()` should work fine! That's a really trivial question, voted to close.

Answer (score 1):

Call `size` function on pointer

```
mapPointer->size()
```

Answer (score 1):

```
mapPointer->size()
```

would give you the size.